# jQuery banner and Dropdown menu problem

Tags: jquery, css, menu, drop-down-menu, banner

Hi I have a problem with jQuery banner and dropdown menu. The dropdown menu is behind the jQuery banner slider. Look for a sample [**here**](http://www.maxline.com.tr/anasayfa).

I tried z-index and position:absolute but I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First, grab [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and use that to embed your flash movie.

Then, set your `wmode` to `opaque` instead of `transparent`, as the transparent wmode is very CPU-demanding and they both respect Z-indexes in the same regard.

It'll look something like this:

```
var so = new SWFObject("XML_Banner.swf", "XML_Banner.swf", "625", "245", "8","#ffffff");
so.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
so.write("flash")
```

Comment: I am so sorry for link. I changed the link you can look again..It is not a flash it is a Jquery slider-banner.

Comment: Your nav menu is going behind your flash movie - you need to fix your flash movie.